# How to make my single page PWA discoverable by Google search?

Tags: seo, firebase

I am looking for a solution to make my single page PWA discoverable to the people searching on Google.

My app is built with Firebase and is a community collaborative jigsaw puzzle database, which means that all users can add records and edit existing records dynamically. The database is Firestore, and the flow of the program is similar to many other similar apps. The user searches somehow, the app retrieves the resulting records and displays it to the user in a smart way.

This all is good and works great, but the Google bot is not happy, as no data exists it drops by to index my site.

This is my basic problem, and I think that many of you may be in a similar situation, so how did you approach this and what experiences do you have?

This is my approach, and let me just say upfront, it is not ideal…

On a regular basis I run a script on my PC, where I retrieve all records, and build dummy html pages, one per puzzle. I put in some meta tags, some Facebook og tags, a title and a h1 title, all with relevant keywords taken from the record in question. I also make sure that each page has at least one link back to my main site (where the PWA reside). I also make sure to build a sitemap.txt file, where all the html files are mentioned, and I do have a robots.txt file which is pointing to my sitemap.

I put all these fake html pages in a folder called static inside my normal folder structure of my PWA build and I make sure that this folder is deployed everytime the PWA is deployed, which happens at least once a week, when the new static folder has been created.

What this nonsense gives me, is a whole lot of html files on my hosting site, which holds info about all the puzzles in my database, in a static content so the Googlebot and others can crawl them and index them. As all the files point back to my PWA, I kind of hope/pray that this will give me some traffic and better ranking. At least it will enable users to search for a puzzle on Google, find my html page, and from there click to the PWA for more info

I am looking for comments or something smarter than this…

Thanks in advance.